# Error typing a RequestHandler - Express JS - TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, types

I want to type a RequestHandler so the req.params and req.body gets type as this interfaces

```
interface UpdateNoteParams {
    noteId: string,
}

interface UpdateNoteBody {
    title?: string,
    text?: string,
}
```

I did this

```
export const updateNote : RequestHandler<UpdateNoteParams, unknown, UpdateNoteBody, unknown> = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction)
```

but i get this error:

```
Type '(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'RequestHandler<UpdateNoteParams, unknown, UpdateNoteBody, unknown, Record<string, any>>'.
  Types of parameters 'req' and 'req' are incompatible.
    Type 'Request<UpdateNoteParams, unknown, UpdateNoteBody, unknown, Record<string, any>>' is not assignable to type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.
      Types of property 'params' are incompatible.
        Type 'UpdateNoteParams' is not assignable to type 'ParamsDictionary'.
          Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'UpdateNoteParams'.ts(2322)
```

i dont know if i need to extend ParamsDictionary or something like that i search a lot but i dont get answer of how to type correctly a RequestHandler

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there, I believe this should work:

```
export const updateNote: RequestHandler<UpdateNoteParams, unknown, UpdateNoteBody, unknown> = async (
  req: Request<UpdateNoteParams, unknown, UpdateNoteBody, unknown>,
  res: Response,
  _next: NextFunction
) => {
  // Now you can use req.params and req.body with the specified types
  const { noteId } = req.params;
  const { title, text } = req.body;

  // ... business logic

  res.status(200).send('Note updated successfully');
};
```